# Hook into a child class SysTreeView32 of VBE window

Tags: api, winapi, vba, parent-child

I am pretty new to the WinApi calls although familiar with VBA. What I am trying to do is to hook to a child class SysTreeView32 of VBE window (Project Explorer TreeView). I would like to expand/collapse the tree view elements by modifying the registry keys (or alternatively sending the mouse clicks (mouse_event) although I prefer the first option).
I can find the Excel Main Window by using this code:

```
Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
              (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Sub Find_Window()
    Dim hWndExcel As Long
    hWndExcel = FindWindow("XLMAIN", Application.Caption)
    MsgBox hWndExcel
End Sub
```

With the help of [Window Detective](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windowdetective/files/) I can access the names, properties, etc. of the child classes. 
[image: Window Detective child classes]

But I cannot work it out how to access/activate(or even return the HWID of) the `SysTreeView32` child class to collapse/expand elements(folders). I am not sure how to iterate over the elements yet, but I will research this afterwards. The problem here is accessing the `SysTreeView32` class. How can I achieve it?

When I try to msgbox this 
`FindWindow("wndclass_desked_gsk", Application.Caption)` 
or
`FindWindow("SysTreeView32", Application.Caption)`
a `0` is returned so I am obviously doing something wrong :/ 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you ought to be using:

```
application.vbe.mainwindow.caption
```

here's some sample collapse code

```
Private Const TVE_COLLAPSE = &H1
Private Const TVE_COLLAPSERESET = &H8000
Private Const TVE_EXPAND = &H2
Private Const TVE_EXPANDPARTIAL = &H4000
Private Const TVE_TOGGLE = &H3
Private Const TV_FIRST = &H1100
Private Const TVM_EXPAND = (TV_FIRST + 2)
Private Const TVM_GETNEXTITEM = (TV_FIRST + 10)
Private Const TVGN_ROOT = &H0
Private Const TVGN_NEXTVISIBLE = &H6

Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
                              (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
                                    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Sub CollapseProjects()
   Dim hWndVBE As Long, hWndPE As Long, hWndTvw As Long, hNode As Long, varReturn
   hWndVBE = FindWindowEx(0, 0, "wndclass_desked_gsk", Application.VBE.MainWindow.Caption)
   hWndPE = FindWindowEx(hWndVBE, 0, "PROJECT", vbNullString)
   hWndTvw = FindWindowEx(hWndPE, 0, "SysTreeView32", vbNullString)
   hNode = SendMessage(hWndTvw, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, TVGN_ROOT, 0&)
   Do While hNode <> 0
      varReturn = SendMessage(hWndTvw, TVM_EXPAND, TVE_COLLAPSE, hNode)
      hNode = SendMessage(hWndTvw, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, TVGN_NEXTVISIBLE, hNode)
   Loop
End Sub
```

further to your comment, here's the code to collapse only the 'Microsoft Excel Objects' nodes

```
Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
                              (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
                                    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SendMessageB Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
                                     (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByRef lParam As Any) As Long

Private Const MAX_ITEM        As Long = 256
Private Const TV_FIRST        As Long = &H1100
Private Const TVM_EXPAND      As Long = (TV_FIRST + 2)
Private Const TVM_GETNEXTITEM As Long = (TV_FIRST + 10)
Private Const TVM_GETITEM     As Long = (TV_FIRST + 12)
Const TVE_COLLAPSE            As Long = &H1
Const TVE_EXPAND              As Long = &H2
Private Const TVGN_ROOT       As Long = &H0
Private Const TVGN_NEXT       As Long = &H1
Private Const TVIF_TEXT       As Long = &H1
Private Const TVGN_NEXTVISIBLE = &H6

Private Type TVITEM   ' was TV_ITEM
   mask                       As Long
   hItem                      As Long
   state                      As Long
   stateMask                  As Long
   pszText                    As String
   cchTextMax                 As Long
   iImage                     As Long
   iSelectedImage             As Long
   cChildren                  As Long
   lParam                     As Long
End Type


Sub CollapseXLObjects()
   Dim hWndVBE                As Long
   Dim hWndPE                 As Long
   Dim hWndTvw                As Long
   Dim hNode                  As Long
   Dim tvi                    As TVITEM
   Dim nChild                 As Long
   Dim sText                  As String
   Dim varReturn

   hWndVBE = FindWindowEx(0, 0, "wndclass_desked_gsk", Application.VBE.MainWindow.Caption)
   hWndPE = FindWindowEx(hWndVBE, 0, "PROJECT", vbNullString)
   hWndTvw = FindWindowEx(hWndPE, 0, "SysTreeView32", vbNullString)

   hNode = SendMessage(hWndTvw, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, TVGN_ROOT, 0&)

   Do While hNode <> 0
      tvi.hItem = hNode
      tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT
      tvi.cchTextMax = MAX_ITEM
      tvi.pszText = String(MAX_ITEM, 0)
      nChild = SendMessageB(hWndTvw, TVM_GETITEM, 0&, tvi)
      If InStr(1, tvi.pszText, "Microsoft Excel Objects", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
         varReturn = SendMessage(hWndTvw, TVM_EXPAND, TVE_COLLAPSE, hNode)
      Else
         varReturn = SendMessage(hWndTvw, TVM_EXPAND, TVE_EXPAND, hNode)
      End If
      hNode = SendMessage(hWndTvw, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, TVGN_NEXTVISIBLE, hNode)
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: +∞ this is just perfect! I am just going to have to modify it to collapse only the Microsoft Excel Objects but I think I will be able to manage it on my own!... well, i dont think i will im just playing with it now and im not fully understanding it yet

Comment: I've updated the code to check the node text and only hide the excel objects

Answer (score 0):

If calling this sub from another sub (in my case a sub in an XL addin linked to a custom button which opens the VBE), and another module is highlighted (which might be in another project) then I've found the

```
    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Caption
```

doesn't work. To capture the highlighted module I use:

```
    Private Sub VisualBasicEditor()
      On Error Resume Next
      WinName = "Microsoft Visual Basic - " + ActiveWorkbook.Name + " [Running] - [" + Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.Name + " (Code)]"
      Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
      Call CollapseXLObjects
    End Sub
```

and in the module containing `Sub CollapseXLObjects` declare

```
    Public WinName As String
```

and in `Sub CollapseXLObjects`

```
    hWndVBE = FindWindowEx(0, 0, "wndclass_desked_gsk", WinName)
```